# Set of solutions with no solution, but one found by manipulation

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Consider the set of equations:
$$
\begin{cases}
x^2 &= -4y-10\\y^2 &= 6z-6\\z^2 &= 2x+2\\
\end{cases}$$

With $x,y,z$ being real numbers.

By adding the three equations, after simple manipulations, we easily obtain
$$
(x-1)^2+(y+2)^2+(z-3)^2=0
$$
Which yields
$$
\begin{cases}
x&=1\\y&=-2\\z&=3\\
\end{cases}
$$
However, plugging that in we find that the solution is invalid. How can one reason about this? In other words, *why* is it invalid? What causes it to be invalid?

[image]

Comment: Your probably squared something and let in extranious solutions.  if $y = -2$ then $x^2 = -4y - 10 = 8-10 = -2$ which is not possible.

Comment: For $x=1, y=-2$ the first equation gives: $1=-2$. Check your algebra again though the approach seems to be solid.

Comment: I get 12 in the right hand side, not 0.

Comment: Right..... adding three equations loses information.  The solution to the sum of three equations gives you just one equation that may have solutions.  But those solutions don't nescessary solve all three equations indivually.  Notice if we mix up all the RHS of the equations you will get a different set of equations with different solutions.  But the solution to the *sum* of all three will stay the same.

Comment: @blamocur: I get $0$ on the right-hand side.

Comment: If you knew that your set of equations _had_ a solution, then your method would work fine. But as it is, you have simply shown that the equations _don't_ have any solutions.

Comment: "If you knew that your set of equations had a solution, then your method would work fine"  Only because the result is $0$ and squares are none negative.  If the sum were a positive number there'd  be infinite solutions to the sums of which only a few would be solutions individually.  Also there are probably complex solutions and this can not find them.

Comment: @fleablood: Yes, of course. I should have said.

Comment: Your argument is a valid conclusion that if $x,y,z$ satisfy the three original equations, then $(x,y,z) = (1,-2,3)$. But remember that "if $P$ then $Q$" is considered true if $P$ is false. Since it's false that real numbers $x,y,z$ can satisfy the three equations, we can get any conclusion from that premise. It's similar to: If $x$ is a real number satisfying $x^2+1 = 0$, then $0 = (x^2+1)(x^2-1) = x^4-1$, so $x^4 = 1$ and $x = \pm 1$. But since neither satisfies $x^2+1=0$, these potential solutions aren't actual solutions; there are no solutions. ...

Comment: (... cont.) Here it's just more obvious that I started with an impossible premise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A solution to three equations will be a solution to the sum of the equations. But the solution to the sum need not be a solution to all three.

Consider $x^2 = 6z-6; y^2 = 2x + 2; z^2 = -4y-10$.  Those are *different* equations and will have different solutions but if you add them you get the same sums.

Even worse we could have $x^2 = -4y+10; y^2 =6z-10; z^2 = 2x - 14$ and the sum will be the same but *obvious* can't have the same solution.

You are basically losing information when you sum them as you are no longer requiring that $x^2$ *must* equal $-4y -10$ (etc) but can be some other combination.

====

An even simpler example could be $2x + 3y + z = 17; x-y+2z =7; x+z = 6$.  Three equations, three unknowns.  One solution $x=2;y=3;z=4$

But if we add them:  $4x + 2y +4z = 30$.  One equation, three unknowns.  Infinite number of solutions of which $x=2;y=3;z=4$ is just one of them.

Comment: I think of it just like Gaussian elimination - you can add (a multiple of) one equation to another, so you are just updating one equation and not throwing away the equation you're adding. In the end you still have 3 equations, the sum equation and two of the original equations.

Comment: A really stupidly obvious example for your first sentence is: The three equations are $x=1$ and $y=2$ and $z=3,$ and the sum of the three equations is $x+y+z=6.$ Now note that things like $(x,y,z)=(3,2,1)$ and $(x,y,z)=(2,2,2)$ and $(x,y,z)=(-100,94,12)$ satisfy the sum of the three equations but not the three equations.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand but yeah, that's about it.  We have $(x-1)^2+(y+2)^2+(z-3)^2=0$ but we *also* have $x^2 = -4 -10$ and other stuff.  All that didn't go way.  It's like if you had $x^2 + y^2= 13$ and $x^2 - y^2 + 4yx = 13$ so $x^2 +y^2 = x^2-y^2 + 4yx$ so $2y^2-4xy = 0$ loses essential information.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thank you.  I don't know why when typing up this answer I thought it would be fruitless to find a linear (and easier) solution when of course it's a perfect example.

Comment: I'm just saying that you can't replace the three equations by the sum of the three equations. All that adding the equations does is give you an additional constraint to work with that might allow one to narrow down the possibilities sufficiently so that one can then return to the original equations and consider them (more successfully) for the smaller set of possibilities, which seems to be what you and the others are saying. I'm just giving an example in which the false logic is immediately apparent, rather than hidden behind a lot of symbol stuff (which the original was, thus hard to spot).

Comment: I'm reminded of things that come up sometimes when finding a derivative by implicit differentiation. Sometimes two different approaches give totally different expressions for the derivative, but theoretically one should be able to show they're equivalent for the restricted values of $(x,y)$ that satisfy $f(x,y)=0.$ Trig identities are likewise similar, in that two expressions that look different can be the same, and radical expressions, etc. Although now the analogy is starting to get pushed a bit far . . .

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I was responding to Jaap Scherphuis and.... I understand what he was saying now.  I'm not sure why I had trouble parsing it the first time I read it.  I need more coffee.

Answer (score 1):

What you found is a necessary but not sufficient condition.  This is what happens in general when you take linear combinations of your initial equations.

If you back substitute, you'll end up with a degree 8 polynomial with 8 complex roots.  The manipulations you did aren't wrong - there are indeed 0 real roots.

Consider the simpler set of equations:
$$x^2=9 \\
y^2=16 \\
z^2=-25$$
By inspection, the 8 roots are $(\pm3,\pm4,\pm5i)$.

If you add the equations, you get
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=0$$
Well, $(0,0,0)$ is clearly a solution of the new equation, but not the original set.  OTOH, if you plug in the 8 true roots into this new derived equation, you will find that it's still true.  So, as I said, necessary but not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I think about it. When you use your initial set of three equations, which I'll call (A), to obtain your final equation, which I'll call (B), what you're saying is the following: "If $x,y,z$ satisfy (A), then they satisfy (B)".

Importantly, this reasoning only gives you a one-sided implication (A implies B), and not necessarily an equivalence (A if and only if B). That is, the converse ("If $x,y,z$ satisfy (B), then they satisfy (A)") may not be true. Indeed, you've found an example where this converse is false: you found $x,y,z$ which satisfy (B) but not (A).

Here's a simpler example. Start with the equality $x=2$, then square both side to get $x^2=4$. What this tells us is: "If $x=2$, then $x^2=4$". But the converse is not true: the equation $x^2=4$ is also satisfied by $x=-2$.